# Make sure a condition return false when mock calling

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a class and the code is provided below,

```
@Service
public class EllaService {

    private static final String SHOP_ID_STRING_SEPARATOR = ",";

    public static final int IRIS_ACCEPT = 0;
    public static final int IRIS_REJECT = 100;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier( ELLA_CONNECTOR_BEAN_NAME )
    private EntityServiceConnectable<EllaResponseDto> connector;

    @Autowired
    @Getter
    private EllaFilterConfigHolder configHolder;

    @Autowired
    @Getter
    private EllaConfiguration config;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    /**
     * Initialize the component.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        createCustomFilters();
    }

    // ========================================================================

    /**
     * Asynchronously call Ella. Determine if traffic is applicable for Ella and if yes forward to Ella.
     *
     * @param irisBo
     * @return List<ResultBo>
     * @throws EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException
     */
    @Async
    public void invokeEllaAsync( final IrisBo irisBo ) throws EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException {

        if( !isTrafficIgnored( irisBo ) ) {

            try {
                callEllaService( irisBo );
            }
            catch( EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException ex ) {
                throw new EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException( ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause() );
            }

        }
    }

    // ========================================================================

    private boolean isTrafficIgnored( IrisBo irisBo ) {

        if( config.isExternalCostumerFilter( this.env ) && irisBo.getBuyer().isExternalKnownCustomer() ) {
            return true;
        }

        if( config.isInternalCostumerFilter( this.env ) && irisBo.getBuyer().isInternalKnownCustomer() ) {
            return true;
        }

        return checkIfShopIdFilterIsApplied( irisBo );

    }

    // ========================================================================

    private boolean checkIfShopIdFilterIsApplied( IrisBo irisBo ) {
        return configHolder.getShopIdsToFilterSet().contains( irisBo.getOrder().getShopId() );

    }

    // ========================================================================

    private void callEllaService( final IrisBo irisBo ) throws EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException {
        HttpHeaders elladHeaders = createRequestHeaders( irisBo );

        ServiceResponse<EllaResponseDto> response = connector.call( EllaDtoConverter.convertToRequest( irisBo ), elladHeaders );

        if( !response.isSuccess() ) {
            throw new EllaGatewayUnsuccessfulResponseException( response.getErrorMessage(), response.getException().getCause() );
        }
    }

    // ========================================================================

    private void createCustomFilters() {
        configHolder.setExternalCustomerFilterEnabled( config.isExternalCostumerFilter( env ) );
        configHolder.setInternalCustomerFilterEnabled( config.isInternalCostumerFilter( env ) );
        configHolder.setShopIdsToFilterSet( new HashSet<>( getShopIdsToFilterAsList( config ) ) );
    }

    // ========================================================================

    private List<Integer> getShopIdsToFilterAsList( EllaConfiguration config ) {
        String shopIdListStr = config.extractShopIdsToFilter( this.env );

        return Arrays.asList( shopIdListStr.split( SHOP_ID_STRING_SEPARATOR ) ).stream().map( s -> Integer.parseInt( s ) )
                .collect( Collectors.toList() );
    }

    // ========================================================================

    private HttpHeaders createRequestHeaders( final IrisBo irisBo ) {

        HttpHeaders ellaHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

        ellaHeaders.add( ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE );
        RatepayHeaders.append( ellaHeaders, irisBo.getRequestInfo() );

        return ellaHeaders;
    }

}
```

I would like to test the `EllaService::invokeEllaAsync` method. How do I mock that when the condition `if( !isTrafficIgnored( irisBo ) )` is checked, it will return `false`?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Is this need to be an UT an IT?

Comment: In general it is adviceable to use constructor or at least setter injection over parameter injection. Spring nowadays [even raises a warning](https://blog.marcnuri.com/field-injection-is-not-recommended/) to not use parameter injection further. This simplifies testing notably as you don't need Spring or any other reflection based utility classes (such as Whitebox, ReflectionUtils, ...) to inject the values into your component or system under test (SUT) but can simply provide these values during construction of the test subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see different ways to do it, one would be:

Introducing a mock for EllaConfiguration and make it return true when `config.isExternalCostumerFilter(any)` is called.
Also make sure `irisBo.getBuyer().isExternalKnownCustomer()` returns true.

This will result in

```
config.isExternalCostumerFilter( this.env ) && irisBo.getBuyer().isExternalKnownCustomer()
```

returning true.
Which will then make `if( !isTrafficIgnored( irisBo ) )` return false.

Answer (score 1):

There are frameworks that help you do exactly that . 
use Mockito 
for example :

```
MyList listMock = Mockito.mock(MyList.class);
doAnswer(invocation -> "Always the same").when(listMock).get(anyInt());

String element = listMock.get(1);
assertThat(element, is(equalTo("Always the same")));
```

you can furture read about Mockito in the official documentation  : 
[here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.27.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html)

Comment: `Mockito` can't be used for private methods. We can use the `PowerMock` for that. I am trying to write that but my code doesn't work so far.

Comment: @Arefe can you show your code? I would also use Mockito and make the 'isTrafficIgnored' method protected and make it return false.

Comment: PowerMockito, you can upload the test you are trying to wirte and we can try and help you with that ...

Comment: If there is a need to mock internal methods (private ones) than there is already a bad smell present in the code. Instead of throwing bigger hammers onto the problem (such as PowerMock), it would be better to rethink the overall design